# How to introduce a new buffer in Base class without wasting extra spaces?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Before========================

```
struct RedBook : Book
{...}

struct BlueBook : Book
{...}

struct YellowBook : Book
{...}

struct Book
{
  virtual ~Book() = default;
  // ...
  static constexpr int COLOR_BOOK_SIZE = 100
  char color_book_buffer[COLOR_BOOK_SIZE] = {0}; // used only by ColorBook(i.e. RedBook/BlueBook/YellowBook)
};
```

Now========================

```
struct GrayBook : Book  // just added
{}

struct DarkBook : Book
{}

struct Book             // updated Book structure
{
  virtual ~Book() = default;
  // ...
  static constexpr int COLOR_BOOK_SIZE = 100
  char color_book_buffer[COLOR_BOOK_SIZE] = {0}; // this buffer is ONLY used by RedBook/BlueBook/YellowBook

  // ...
  static constexpr int NOCOLOR_BOOK_SIZE = 200
  char no_color_book_buffer[NOCOLOR_BOOK_SIZE] = {0}; // this buffer is ONLY used by GrayBook/DarkBook
};
```

The code was written only required for ColorBook (i.e. support RedBook/BlueBook/YellowBook).
All ColorBook use color_book_buffer.

Now the design requirement has changed and I need to add support for NoColorBook(i.e. GrayBook/DarkBook). All NoColorBook only use no_color_book_buffer.

**Question**> I don't like to add both buffers(i.e. color_book_buffer and no_color_book_buffer) into the struct Book because it wastes space.
Also I don't like the proposed two solutions shown below.
Is there a better way that I can address this issue?

**Solution 1**> I can move buffer definition into subclass but this will introduce duplicated code within each subclass.

**Solution 2**> I can add an extra layer as follows:

```
struct ColorBook
{
  virtual ~ColorBook() = default;
  // ...
  static constexpr int COLOR_BOOK_SIZE = 100
  char color_book_buffer[COLOR_BOOK_SIZE] = {0};
};

struct RedBook : ColorBook
{...}

struct BlueBook : ColorBook
{...}

struct YellowBook : ColorBook
{...}

struct NonColorBook
{
  virtual ~NonColorBook() = default;
  // ...
  static constexpr int NOCOLOR_BOOK_SIZE = 200
  char no_color_book_buffer[NOCOLOR_BOOK_SIZE] = {0};
};

struct GrayBook : NonColorBook
{}

struct DarkBook : NonColorBook
{}
```

**Solution 3**> I found another solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct ColorMessage
{
  int a;
  double b;
  std::string message;
};

struct NonColorMessage
{
  float a;
  double b;
  bool has_message;
};

constexpr unsigned int MAX_COLOR_MSG_COUNT = 3;
constexpr unsigned int MAX_NON_COLOR_MSG_COUNT = 2;

struct Book
{
  virtual ~Book() = default;

  static constexpr int COLOR_MSG_SIZE = sizeof(ColorMessage) * MAX_COLOR_MSG_COUNT;
  static constexpr int NOCOLOR_MSG_SIZE = sizeof(NonColorMessage) * MAX_COLOR_MSG_COUNT;
  char book_buffer[std::max(COLOR_MSG_SIZE, NOCOLOR_MSG_SIZE)] = {0};
};

struct RedBook : Book
{};

struct BlueBook : Book
{};

struct YellowBook : Book
{};

struct GrayBook : Book
{};

struct DarkBook : Book
{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(ColorMessage): " << sizeof(ColorMessage) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(NonColorMessage): " << sizeof(NonColorMessage) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Book::COLOR_MSG_SIZE: " << Book::COLOR_MSG_SIZE << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Book::NOCOLOR_MSG_SIZE: " << Book::NOCOLOR_MSG_SIZE << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(Book::book_buffer): " << sizeof(Book::book_buffer) << std::endl;
}

/*

sizeof(ColorMessage): 48
sizeof(NonColorMessage): 24
Book::COLOR_MSG_SIZE: 144
Book::NOCOLOR_MSG_SIZE: 72
sizeof(Book::book_buffer): 144
*/
```

Thank you

Comment: Your solution 2 that you don't like is what I would suggest you use.  Why don't you like it?

Comment: Oops, just missed one detail.  I would have both `ColorBook` and `NonColorBook` inherit from `Book`

Comment: What's the buffer used for? You could probably simplify it by making it `std::string buffer` or `std::vector<char> buffer` in the `Book` base class and let the `ColorBook`/`NonColorBook` classes decide what size it should have. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps77jMr7d)

Comment: As a variation to your solution 2, make the base abstract with a non-static int bookSize and char *bookBuffer; that are setup in the Colorbook & NonColorBook constructors using the members they introduce. Adds a bit of memory and an indirection, but doesn't get into dynamic allocation. If dynamic allocation is OK, do what @TedLyngmo suggests.

Comment: Another variation to that what @AviBerger suggested, that doesn't consume any more memory, dynamic allocation or introduce indirection could be to add a `BufferedBook` class to the mix which just holds a `std::array` of the wanted size. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/MedGn8fMx)

Comment: Are you wanting to pass/store both the `ColorBook` and `NonColorBook`'s polymorphically? I.e. You have some function that takes a reference to a `Book` and it doesn't know if it's a `ColorBook` or a `NonColorBook`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this was mentioned in the comments but you could add another `class` to the hierarchy which just holds the buffer (`std::array`).

The `read`, `write` and `count` functions are for illustration purposes only.

```
struct book {
    virtual void read() const = 0;
    virtual void write(const std::string_view content) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t count() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual ~book() = default;
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct book_buffer : book {
    std::array<char, N> buffer{};
}; 

struct color_book : book_buffer<200> {
    void read() const override {
        std::cout << "Reading color book: " << buffer.data() << '\n';
    }

    void write(const std::string_view content) override {
        std::copy(content.begin(), content.end(), buffer.begin());
    }

    std::size_t count() const noexcept override {
        return buffer.size();
    }
};


struct monochromatic_book : book_buffer<100> {
    void read() const override {
        std::cout << "Reading monochromatic book: " << buffer.data() << '\n';
    }

    void write(const std::string_view content) override {
        std::copy(content.begin(), content.end(), buffer.begin());
    }

    std::size_t count() const noexcept override {
        return buffer.size();
    }
};

struct red_book : monochromatic_book 
{};

struct rainbow_book : color_book
{};

static void open_book(const book& b) {
    b.read();
    std::cout << "Size: " << b.count() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    rainbow_book b1{};
    b1.write("All the colors!");

    red_book b2{};
    b2.write("I just like red!");

    open_book(b1);
    open_book(b2);
}
```